# stopping procedure when using dropout?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dropout

I'm currently implementing a neural network that makes use of dropout. A question that came up was when to stop training.

Normally I would use early stopping to determine that point but in the original [dropout-paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580.pdf) it is stated that "dropout allows much larger nets to be trained and **removes the need for early stopping**."

If they don't apply early stopping what stopping procedure do they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early stopping refers to some scheme of stopping the training once you get good enough results, or once you stop seeing significant improvements for a while.

Their stopping procedure is just "run the training for `x` number of iterations / epochs".